# Calling a variable from a variable

Tags: shell, ksh

I am trying to get this bit of script ready to put into a for loop.

```
#!/bin/ksh
variable=40
x="able"
y=\$vari$x
echo $y
```

The out put for this is:

```
$variable
```

It's almost there, I tried using `` to no avail. I searched for some solutions but most seemed to revolve around putting two variable together as opposed to using a variable to call another variable. I hope I am not rambling too much

Comment: In `bash`, you'd use `${!y}`.  In `ksh`, you need `eval echo $y`.  But `eval` is, in general, dangerous.  Be cautious with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ksh`, use `eval`:

```
#!/bin/ksh
variable=40
x="able"
y=\$vari$x
eval echo $y
```

This prints `40` as required.  Be aware that `eval` is, in general, dangerous; be cautious about using it.

---

In `bash`, you can (almost) use `${!y}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
variable=40
x="able"
y=vari$x
echo ${!y}
```

Note, however, that the value in `y` is just `variable`, not `$variable` as in the `ksh` code.
This is safer to use than `eval`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, out of curiosity what makes eval dangerous?

Comment: Consider ``x='`rm -fr /`'; eval echo $x;`` and don't try it on your machine.  If you're completely in control of what's in the `eval`'d variables, it is safe.  If you take any unsanitized user input and use it in `eval`, you are leaving yourself at the mercy of the user.